# Interference pattern from a diffraction on a opaque disk vs circular aperture

Tags: optics, waves, classical-electrodynamics, interference, diffraction

I have been reading up on diffraction theory and found out about Babinet's principle which states that the wave resulting from a diffraction on an aperature is the same wave resulting from a diffraction on a complementary obstacle within a phase difference. Basically, interference patter on a screen should be the same.

Looking at the interference pattern of a circular aperature and a opaque disk, they are not the same, more like complementary to each other which contradicts with my understanding of Babinet's principle.

I assume I understood something wrong here, but i am not sure what. Some refrences and/or math are appreciated if possible.

Comment: is the geometry the same except one is opaque?  ie you just put opaque materia infront of the hole> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babinet%27s_principle

Comment: You need to be quite far away to get the diffraction pattern outside the direct beam. In my course lab, students do this with a laser that is blocked by a copper wire or by a strand of hair. The screen is at five meters distance.